# Error in connecting R to Oracle database using RODBC

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am trying to connect R to an Oracle database. I am getting an error which I have already tried to trouble shoot but not able to find a solution.

I created a DSN and successfully tested the connection

[image: Successfully connection]

I then tried to establish a connection in R.

```
con <- odbcConnect("DSNNAME", uid='ID', pwd='PWD')
```

But I receive an error.

```
 Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSNNAME;UID=ID;PWD=PWD") :
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM014, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSNNAME;UID=ID;PWD=PWD") :
ODBC connection failed
```

I have replaced my id and password with dummies.

Also I am using 64 bit R.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using a 64-bit ODBC driver?

Comment: Check **both** RODBC and the ODBC driver are either 32 or 64 bits. You cannot mix 32/64 bits driver/apps.